# Return 'null' Instead Of Error When Field Does Not Exist On Record

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'd like to share a trigger function between several tables. Within the trigger function I'd like to mostly ignore which table caused the trigger.

| Table A | Table B |
| --- | --- |
| ColA | ColB |
| Id | Id |

Inside my trigger function I'd like to do something like `coalesce(new.ColA, new.ColB)` but that results in an error:

> record "new" has no field "ColB"

And that's absolutely true. But is there any way to avoid duplicating a lot of similar code when what I've really got is half a dozen fields that I want to access if they exist, but gracefully ignore/treat as null, when they aren't around? I know I can inspect `TG_TABLE_NAME` if I have to, it's just making things very verbose in my function.

Comment: You can trap the error: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: @FrankHeikens - the error handling has significant overhead, and when there are some second way, then is better to used second way. In this case, the inspection TG_TABLE_NAME should be preferred.

Comment: @PavelStehule: I'm aware of it, but it's still an option if you don't want to use TG_TABLE_NAME

Comment: I've never tried this, but can you do a `to_jsonb(new)` inside of your trigger function?

Comment: I've had success pulling up the complexity one level and generating triggers, this way when you look at the trigger you see that it does only exactly what it needs to do. Shared logic is injected in the definitions. The code-generation can get a bit wonky, but I've found that `plpgsql` is not the ideal place for introspection, reflection, and dynamicism. There's always json and hstore if you're in a bind though.